# How to recursively split a linked list after k nodes in C++?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I have an ordinary linked list with:

```
struct node{
  int info;
  node* next;
};
```

I need to write a recursive function that splits in 2 a given linked list passed by reference after k elements, leaving the first k nodes in this list and returning the second list with the rest of the nodes.

My iterative solutions looks like this:

```
node* split(node*&L, int k){
   node* M;
   node* head = L;
   while(k>1){
      head=head->next;
      k--;
   }
   M = head->next;
   head->next = NULL;
   return M;
}


Output:
L: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
after split with: k = 3
L: 1 2 3 
M: 4 5 6
```

Which seems to work just fine. Now i can't really think of a recursive solution for this. I was trying with:

```
node* splitL(node*&L, int k){
   if(!L) return 0;
   if(k<=1){
      node* x = L->next;
      L->next =  NULL;
      return x;
   }
   L->next = splitL(L->next, k-1);
   return L;

}
```

Which is obviously wrong because it's returning x into L->next so both lists become 1 2 3 4 5 6.

How do I write a recursive function for this? The parameters and the return type should stay the same. Also it would be great if someone could explain how I could translate my iterative solution to a recursive one.

Comment: This does not sound like needing recursion. What makes you think that it is needed?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate success of on-recursion and failure of recursion approach.

Comment: Why you modify the value of L->next: `L->next = splitL(L->next, k-1);`. I think it would be enough with the call `splitL(L->next, k-1);` and returning that value

Comment: I did not say that recursion is needed to solve this problem, I obviously solved it with an iterative function. I am learning recursion and this is an exercise I got stuck on.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff: Yes you're right, that would have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have

```
node* split(node*&L, int k){
   node* M;
   node* head = L;
   while(k>1){
      head=head->next;
      k--;
   }
   M = head->next;
   head->next = NULL;
   return M;
}
```

You want something like

```
node* split(node*&L, int k){
   node* M;
   node* head = splitPoint(L, k);
   M = head->next;
   head->next = NULL;
   return M;
}

node* splitPoint(node*&L, int k){
   if (k <= 0)
     return L;
   return splitPoint(L->next, k - 1);
}
```

Note neither this nor your original guards for `k` greater than the length of the list.

Single-function version:

```
node* split(node*&L, int k){
   if (k <= 0)
   {
     node* head = L;
     node* M = head->next;
     head->next = NULL;
     return M;
   }
   return split(L->next, k - 1);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but the thing is I am allowed to use only one function not two.

Comment: @norislav: I added a single-function version.

Comment: If I decide to use two functions they both have to be recursive. The function split from your example is not.

Comment: @norislav: See my last `split()` - it is independent from the rest.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the comment. Yes, that's it! It should be if (k<=1) but the rest is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

At first I didn't see the point of passing your list pointer by reference, but then I found out it is key to the implementation.

I think you could do this:

- Check for a null input list; it could be that you were asked to split the input list beyond the end of it (`k > list size`).
- Check for `k == 0`; this is the point to do the split, so 1) return the current `head` and 2) set previous node's `next` pointer to null (or the list pointer itself if this were the first call); you do that just setting `head` to null, because `head` is a reference to the pointer you used in the call to `split_list`.
- Otherwise, call `split_list` recursively.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/rb6j6dohd)

```cpp
node* split_list(node*& head, int k)
{
    if (!head) { return nullptr; }
    if (k == 0) { node* ret{head}; head = nullptr; return ret; }
    return split_list(head->next, k-1);
}
```